# Error al hacer conexión con App.config

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando con C# Windows Form y SQLServer en un conexionString dinámico, modificando el APP.CONFIG, pero estoy recibiendo el siguiente error al tratar de conectar:

**Keyword not supported: 'datasource'**

Como soluciono ese error, para poder conectar correctamente la base de datos.

Este es el código que tengo del formulario:

```
namespace PruebaAppConfig
```

{
public partial class frm_Conex : Form
{
public frm_Conex()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    private void frm_DynamicallyConString_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cboServer.Items.Add(".");
        cboServer.Items.Add("(local)");
        cboServer.Items.Add(@".\SQLEXPRESS");
        cboServer.Items.Add(string.Format(@"{0}\SQLEXPRESS", Environment.MachineName));
        cboServer.Items.Add("3");
    }

    private void btnCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = string.Format("Datasource={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};", cboServer.Text, txtDb.Text, txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        try
        {
            SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper(connectionString);
            if (helper.IsConnection)
                MessageBox.Show("Connection has been succeeded.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set connection string
        string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};", cboServer.Text, txtDb.Text, txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        try
        {
            SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper(connectionString);
            if (helper.IsConnection)
            {
                AppSetting setting = new AppSetting();
                setting.SaveConnectionString("cn", connectionString);
                MessageBox.Show("Your connection string has been successfully saved.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Y esta es mi clase de configuracion:

```
public class AppSetting
{
    Configuration config;

    public AppSetting()
    {
        config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    }

    //Get connection string from App.Config file
    public string GetConnectionString(string key)
    {
        return config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
    }

    //Save connection string to App.config file
    public void SaveConnectionString(string key, string value)
    {
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString = value;
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda que se pueda brindar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La palabra clave a usar no es `Datasource` sino `Data Source`

```
string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};", cboServer.Text, txtDb.Text, txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese era el problema @F.Igor